# Nodes from private network don't gossip

Tags: nodes, bootnodes

I have three Ethereum nodes created with Geth. Two of them are on my machine (MacOS) and the third one is running on a virtual machine with Ubuntu. Because I used the same genesis.json and also the same networkid I can connect them, but the problem is that they don't gossip about already connected nodes.

Let's consider A, B and C being the nodes:

1. I start node A.
2. I start node B with the argument --bootnodes "enode of A" and after a while they are connected (they see each other in admin.peers).
3. I start C without bootnodes. Manually, I add B as a peer using admin.addPeer(). At this point B and C are connected BUT B doesn't gossip with C about A.

At the end of the scenario A knows about B, C knows about B and B knows about both A and C.

On this page: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network they say that Ethereum nodes gossip about each other. Am I doing something wrong?